# I cant install zip (.tar) files using desktop from other Linux Ubuntu downloads

Tags: software-installation, slingshot, thirdpartyapps, download, gnome-terminal

My problem is the following
Who knows how?
I'm not talking about the Elemementary App Store downloads.
I mean programs from other official sites like for Epson printer drivers and scanners, where there is NO link/address to use "apt-get install <…>" etc. in terminal code.
When I use the download button and unzip the download it opens bit I cant see the '.exe' button, only the folders * files - so it's not visible' in the "Apps" window - thus useless.
When I try to open in in terminal editor I get: " unable to locate file" etc. 
So could you tell me how to, preferably, get the get the terminal address from the button on the download site
or
How to install the downloaded zip/.tar using the terminal code, with the correct folder indicators - thus a few lines of code plz.

---

this is what the terminal says:[image]

---

See image .. it's what Eddy says about the iScan installation & yes I am trying to open the 770 64bit tar gz .. Btw Eddy also says this for my Vuex (vuescan) package, but I did manage to install that and it starts to run but needs the iscan plugin ..... So can you help again plz?
[image]

[image: eddy]

---

See image .. it's what Eddy says about the iScan installation & yes I am trying to open the 770 64bit tar gz .. Btw Eddy also says this for my Vuex (vuescan) package, but I did manage to install that and it starts to run but needs the iscan plugin ..... So can you help again plz?[image]

---

OK here is what I get, it seems to be installed but does not seem to get into the Vuescan or iScan app.
But non of my usb printers connect either, one says it's printing but I get no result on paper(WF-2010) . My Stylus pro 3800 just does nothing .. so maybe we should look at how to check  if the usb periphials are visible.
Btw I do see external usb HDD's when I connect them,

[image]

---

[image]It seems that I can only send one image at a time here so sorry for all the posts[image]

---

It seems that I can only send one image at a time here so sorry for all the posts[image]

---

OK, now I found the problem with the screenshots.
Also i tried the Terminal fix suggested in the instructions, bit to no avail :(
Get the same fault report.
Can you help please?
see attachments[fault message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gqNV.png)

[image]

Comment: I suspect, there may be more than one question in your question. Could you please provide an example of a third-party driver/software that you wanted to manually install in elementary OS but didn't succeed?

Comment: And would you please clarify, what '.exe' button are you referring to?

Comment: I am trying to install the printer driver for Epson WF-2010 & scan driver for Epson V-500. with .exe I mean the run/boot to launch the drivers.

Comment: I am trying to install the printer driver for Epson WF-2010 & scan driver for Epson V-500. with .exe I mean the run/boot to launch the drivers.         see Perfection V500 scanner driver here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule     AND have installed the WF-2010 printerdriver, but it gives "connect printer cable, while when I change to Windows 10 on the same computer it works

Comment: I did follow a link you provided. There was only one Linux driver for Epson V-500 (available on this page: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-x770&version=1.0.1) After unpacking it produced a folder with 3 folders in it, with .deb install files in each of them. You can install .deb files easily with the help of Eddy app (from the AppCenter).

Comment: As to Epson WF-2010, there was only Windows driver found on the page you provided. Which, obviously, can't be installed on Linux.

Comment: if you look you'll be linked to a 3erd party page which has the driver

Comment: here are the instructions for the scanner download -  they don't work in my Elementary Unduntu etc. do you know?   Here is the download: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-x770&version=1.0.1   and the instructions http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1

Comment: so here is the printer driver that I managed to install. but it can't find my printer usb, while windows10 works perfectly on the same computer >>>>   http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: #a.tokarev here is what I get when I try to open iscan.
also how do I put the plugin into my Vuescan app? screenshot [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXNqz.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXNqz.jpg)

Comment: If you intentionally scrambled the text on your screenshot, why did you do it? How is one supposed to read and understand it?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I definitely didn't scramble the text, I have no idea how this happened :( I just used the standard screen shot app, but now that I see it on my Windows laptop I can understand what you mean. When I ge back to my workstation I shall try to make another screenshot using the whole screen option

Comment: OK now I've found the problem with the screenshots see my images.

Comment: nice post thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the screenshot. Is this the Epson Perfection V500 driver that you are trying to install?[image]
...

**UPD:** If the manufacturer's installation instructions have failed, here's what you could try:

1. Go to your `AppCenter`. In the search field, type **Eddy** (this is a handy .deb packages installation helper), select and install Eddy application.
2. Download the scanner driver archive from the Epson link. Make sure to choose .deb 64bit(amd64) version, if your processor is 64bit. In this case, the name of the archive will be `iscan-gt-x770-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz`.
3. In `Files` browser, right-click the downloaded archive and select `Extract Here`. This will extract the archive into the folder "iscan-gt-x770-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb".
4. Go to that folder. There you will find three more folders (core, data, plugins). Inside each of these folders you will find a file with a `.deb` extension. Double-click each of these .deb files and install them with Eddy. Reboot if necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes indeed - I have also tried Vuescan, but Ed(the developer) says I need the Epson plugin first.  Do you have a clear solution for me? If it's in terminal code then could you please send the exact code, as I'm new toLinux

Comment: I will update my answer above.

Comment: please do, I'm very curious

Comment: already done yesterday )) see my answer above, four steps after **UPD**

Comment: I use Eddy, but when I click the subfolders you mention I get terminal editor :(

Comment: somehow this app won't send images now, but I do get a message yaht the plugin is installed. OK here is what I get, it seems to be installed but does not seem to get into the Vuescan or iScan app. But non of my usb printers connect either, one says it's printing but I get no result on paper(WF-2010) . My Stylus pro 3800 just does nothing .. so maybe we should look at how to check if the usb periphials are visible, if you have the time and energy, or maybe you know a quick way in terminal?

Comment: Is your printer visible in `System Settings` > `Printers` ?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your scanner. When running commands in Terminal, exclude hashtag symbol (#) from your command lines. For example, instead of:

```
#/etc/init.d/udev
```

enter and run:

```
/etc/init.d/udev
```

Try and see if your system sees the scanner.

Comment: It seems that Mr. Hasan has blocked me so it's difficult to respond, but your tip re. the hashtag worked. When I tried > usr/bin/iscan I get "failed to load moduele 'pantheon-file ...etc

Comment: If the tip was helpful and your scanner finally works, then please mark this comment as helpful and close the question.

Comment: @BillieGlaser, Hello! Please let me clarify the situation. I deleted your posted answers, because those were not answers. Answers field is to post direct [solution to the question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Your posts were more accurate as update to your situation so I removed those and added in the question. Sorry I didn't notice your comment, i should have explained earlier. Please do mention me or any mod in future if you ever feel that somethings wrong. Have a nice day!

Comment: OK Hasan, most polite af you to answer after all this time, but unforturately you disturbed my interaction with A-Tokarev who has been a great help to me re. installation of Epson software, which is not easy on my Elementary Ubunti OS.
so could you please unblock me so that i can finish the final stage of installing my Epson V500 scanner.
He has already successfully helped me with the installations of my Epson WF-2010 and my 3800.
Sincerely,
Billie